# Summing up rows with the same column IDs, of matrices in a list

Tags: r, matrix, sum

Let's say that we have the following list with some matrices inside (it could be many but for simplicity, I'm putting two for now)

```
> rel$E
      i   j   value             
 [1,] "3" "5" "0.070711136732969"  
 [2,] "3" "6" "0.0555555555555557" 
 [3,] "1" "3" "0.0178395371187627" 
 [4,] "1" "2" "0.00488002262797937"
 [5,] "2" "5" "0.0272189957856598" 
 [6,] "3" "4" "0.0438244348035453" 
 [7,] "2" "4" "0.0128664170608579" 
 [8,] "3" "3" "0"                  
 [9,] "2" "3" "0.0167431138932832" 
[10,] "2" "2" "0"                  
[11,] "4" "5" "0.0180208592355387" 
[12,] "2" "6" "0.028063474878704"  
[13,] "1" "5" "0.00937210021651717"
[14,] "1" "4" "0.0033698603568658" 
> rel$D
      i   j   value             
 [1,] "1" "3" "0.0398765637816322" 
 [2,] "1" "1" "0"                  
 [3,] "1" "4" "0.00452411512576561"
 [4,] "3" "4" "0.0193536780493677" 
 [5,] "1" "2" "0.00289466496926153"
 [6,] "2" "5" "0.0283053038069326" 
 [7,] "3" "3" "0"                  
 [8,] "3" "6" "0.0862179235688977" 
 [9,] "1" "5" "0.0242662144621697" 
[10,] "1" "6" "0.00584795321637427"
[11,] "4" "5" "0.0174208488656519" 
[12,] "2" "3" "0.0443079152300233" 
[13,] "2" "2" "0"                  
[14,] "2" "4" "0.0131264776661371" 
[15,] "3" "5" "0.0952553775375157"
```

What I want to achieve is, to sum up, all `values` columns of the matrix that have the same `i` & `j`.

For example for `i=3`, `j=5` the sum should be `0.070711136732969 + 0.0952553775375157`.

But there are some pairs as you can see that exist to one but not to the other matrix.

For such a case `i=1`, `j=6` the sum should be `0 + 0.00584795321637427` because this pair doesn't exist in the first matrix.

Is there any efficient (lapply,apply) way to produce a final matrix with columns `i, j, sum`? But without using many for loops? I tried to approached it with for loops but the final code became hard to read and change.

Comment: `aggregate()` is your friend. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family Your data seems to be a matrix - so you eventually have to coerce to a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `rbind` and `aggregate`, i.e.

```
aggregate(value ~ i+j, do.call(rbind, l2), sum)
```

which gives,

> ```
>    i j       value
> 1  1 1 0.000000000
> 2  1 2 0.007774688
> 3  2 2 0.000000000
> 4  1 3 0.057716101
> 5  2 3 0.061051029
> 6  3 3 0.000000000
> 7  1 4 0.007893975
> 8  2 4 0.025992895
> 9  3 4 0.063178113
> 10 1 5 0.033638315
> 11 2 5 0.055524300
> 12 3 5 0.165966514
> 13 4 5 0.035441708
> 14 1 6 0.005847953
> 15 2 6 0.028063475
> 16 3 6 0.141773479
> ```

**DATA**

```
dput(l2)
list(structure(c(3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 
6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 4, 0.070711136732969, 0.0555555555555557, 
0.0178395371187627, 0.00488002262797937, 0.0272189957856598, 
0.0438244348035453, 0.0128664170608579, 0, 0.0167431138932832, 
0, 0.0180208592355387, 0.028063474878704, 0.00937210021651717, 
0.0033698603568658), .Dim = c(14L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("i", "j", "value"))), structure(c(1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 5, 6, 5, 3, 2, 
4, 5, 0.0398765637816322, 0, 0.00452411512576561, 0.0193536780493677, 
0.00289466496926153, 0.0283053038069326, 0, 0.0862179235688977, 
0.0242662144621697, 0.00584795321637427, 0.0174208488656519, 
0.0443079152300233, 0, 0.0131264776661371, 0.0952553775375157
), .Dim = c(15L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("i", "j", "value"
))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to add that I had to convert my matrix into numeric for the sum function to work.